# How to force light `color-scheme` styles in 3rd party HTML, regardless of `prefers-color-scheme`

Tags: css

I'm rendering emails in my application. The emails come with CSS defined by 3rd parties. Some of those 3rd parties style their emails with `prefers-color-scheme` media queries. The problem is, my application doesn't (yet) support a dark theme. When an email's text is rendered in "dark mode" but on a light background, it often becomes unreadable.

**How can I specify that my application doesn't support a dark mode (i.e. force the "light" `color-scheme` regardless of the browser's `prefer-color-scheme` setting)?** Adding `:root { color-scheme: light; }` (or `:root { color-scheme: light !important; }` doesn't have any affect.

Thanks! I wasn't able to find an example of this question already being asked.